# Why does twitter's share button add data-twttr-rendered="true" to my body tag?

Tags: javascript, twitter

Just curious. Why would it need access to *that* part of the DOM, and not just the part it's manipulating?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Seems to be that the twitter button's render callback needs to know if the whole page has been rendered (especially if you have more than one on a page), and the body tag is an obvious place to store that information by means of an attribute...

Tweet button docs: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button

Look up also `twttr.TweetButton` and its method `render()`

For confirmation have an explore of this code: http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js
(do a search for `data-twttr-rendered` to see it used - it is minified unfortunately however!)